# Python Method to find minimum occurence

Tags: python, methods, min

Im trying to write a method in Python that finds which card is the rarest by finding minimum number of occurrences. Im also trying to return the name and colors associated for these. Can someone help me write this in a more effective manner? I can count the occurrences, get the colors and put them in a list, and get the names in a list. But how can i do this besides putting it in all separate lists? I can post more code but the rarity types are Uncommon, Common, Rare and mythic rare.

Code:

```
def get_rarest_card(self):
    uncommon_counter = 0
    common_counter = 0
    rare_counter = 0
    mythic_rare_counter =0
    mythic_rare_cards=[]
    uncommon_color_list=[]
    common_color_list=[]
    rare_color_list=[]
    mythicrare_color_list=[]

for eachCard in self.cardlist:
    if eachCard.rarity=="Uncommon":
        uncommon_counter = uncommon_counter + 1
        uncommon_color_list.append(eachCard.get_colors())
    elif eachCard.rarity=="Common":
        common_counter=common_counter + 1
        common_color_list.append(eachCard.get_colors())
    elif eachCard.rarity=="Rare":
        rare_counter = rare_counter + 1
        rare_color_list.append(eachCard.get_colors())
    elif eachCard.rarity=="Mythic Rare":
        mythic_rare_cards.append(eachCard.get_name())
        mythic_rare_counter = mythic_rare_counter + 1
        mythicrare_color_list.append(eachCard.get_colors())
return(mythic_rare_cards)
```

Comment: Why separate lists per rarity? Do you want the rarest card overall or the rarest one for each class?

Comment: We are looking for the cards that appear the least (i.e. the rarest). Then figure out which colors are associated with those cards

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Xaerxess no, it doesn't. It asks for a new feature or alternative variant, which is off-topic on CR. If it gets cleaned up and explains what the code does, it might be on-topic. But it really needs to get cleaned up first. [See also this guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` could help you here:

```
from collections import Counter
card_rarities = Counter(card.rarity for card in self.cardlist)
rarity = min(card_rarities, key=lambda card: card_rarities[card])  # Effectively an argmin
return [card for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity == rarity]
```

Anything hashable can be put through this process, so you can get the least common rarity, color, or specific card depending on what you feed into `Counter`.

Comment: what would r be? When i ran it, it said r is not defined

Comment: i put in "rarity" which is what its called in the JSON object? Is that what its looking for?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Ive done that and now im trying to get it to print out. Im getting this <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b506b00>

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be `card`. You're finding the minimum "card", where the key says that cards are compared in terms of the number of times they show up. Note that this will be unstable if you have multiple cards with the same minimum (e.g., multiple cards that show up only once). To fix this, consider using `sorted` instead of `min`, then looking at the beginning of the array to find the rarest cards.

Comment: How you print cards is up to you, it's just an object that apparently you've defined or imported from somewhere that you don't mention in your question above. If this answer solves what you originally asked, please accept the answer and open a new question regarding your new problem.

Comment: Im sorry my question might have been not clear. We are looking for the cards that fall under the rarest rarity (I know Mythic Rare is going to have the least number of cards) and I want to print out which cards fall under the Mythic Rare rarity type

Comment: Ah, well that's even easier. If all you want is to filter the card list by those that are Mythic Rare, just use a simple list comprehension. See my second answer for an example of this.

Comment: The answer above works! How would i print the colors that are associated with these card names?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_rarest_cards():
    return [card for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity.lower() == 'mythic rare']
```

How you print them is up to you. Maybe by name?

```
mythics = my_cards.get_rarest_cards()
for card in mythics:
    print(card.get_name())
```

Comment: This works but im not supposed to know which has the least. I just know cux i checked. So i need to check a count of different types and figure out what is the least